# 100 comma separated random counter position Values make a sum and show last 60 minutes stats

Tags: sql, oracle, pentaho

I am trying to display last 60 minutes statistics on pentaho dashboard (oracle 11g query passing to pentaho ).
I have column (counter_buff) in my table with 1000 counter positions with sample data shown below

```
counter_buff= '0,8,9,3,2,6,....15,62'  up to 1000 comma seperated values
```

i am trying to fetch each comma separated values from table as per fixed positions provided and sum them, so the problem is if i use multiple positions query gets bigger & slower, slower query result in delayed statistics on dashboard.

I created this sample query & result:

Query:

the Numbers showing in {} is a counter positions({16},{24}..), this positions will be user defined. query also using 6 union all same like this.

```
select * from
((SELECT MIN(to_char(TIMESTAMP,'HH24:MI:SS')) as TS,
         'SELL' as "STATUS",
         SUM((regexp_substr(counter_buff,'(.*?,){16}(.*?),', 1, 1,'', 2)) +
             (regexp_substr(counter_buff,'(.*?,){24}(.*?),', 1, 1,'', 2)) +
             (regexp_substr(counter_buff,'(.*?,){32}(.*?),', 1, 1,'', 2)) ......+
             (regexp_substr(counter_buff,'(.*?,){168}(.*?),', 1, 1,'', 2))) AS  "COUNTS"
    FROM (SELECT * FROM SHOPS
          order by TO_CHAR("TIMESTAMP",'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') desc) "SHOPS"
   where TOY_NAME = 'LION'
     and rownum <=60
   GROUP BY TO_CHAR("TIMESTAMP",'HH24:MI'))
  UNION ALL
 (SELECT MIN(to_char(TIMESTAMP,'HH24:MI:SS')) as TS,
         'RETURNED' as "STATUS",
         SUM((regexp_substr(counter_buff,'(.*?,){17}(.*?),', 1, 1,'', 2)) +
             (regexp_substr(counter_buff,'(.*?,){25}(.*?),', 1, 1,'', 2)) ..... +
             (regexp_substr(counter_buff,'(.*?,){153}(.*?),', 1, 1,'', 2)) +
             (regexp_substr(counter_buff,'(.*?,){161}(.*?),', 1, 1,'', 2)) +
             (regexp_substr(counter_buff,'(.*?,){169}(.*?),', 1, 1,'', 2))) AS "COUNTS"
    FROM (SELECT * FROM SHOPS
          order by TO_CHAR("TIMESTAMP",'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') desc) "SHOPS"
   where TOY_NAME = 'LION'
     and rownum <=60
   GROUP BY TO_CHAR("TIMESTAMP",'HH24:MI')) )
order by TS desc,STATUS desc
```

result:

this is just some rows of result, result will be as per query rowid (to reduce space i pasted half result only , but i am using data of 60 last minutes)

```
TS          STATUS       COUNTS
10:20:01    SELL         6
10:21:01    SELL         9
10:22:01    SELL         8
10:23:01    SELL         3

10:20:01    RETURNED     1
10:21:01    RETURNED     6  
10:22:01    RETURNED     7
10:23:01    RETURNED     2
```

I am able to achieve my desired output, But i want faster & smaller query option.

I am new to oracle query

Comment: When using a database, only store comma-separated values, if you are not interested in the separate values. If you *are* interested in separate values, then store them separately.

Answer (score 1):

You should filter data as much as possible at first, then make rest of job. Also `union` is not needed, you can do everything in one grouping, then only unpivot result if needed. 
Below two queries, which should be useful. In first you have to write `regexp_substr` as many times as needed:

```
/* sample data
with shops(toy_name, time_stamp, counter_buff) as (
    select 'LION', timestamp '2018-07-27 13:15:27', '0,8,9,3,2,6,15,62'    from dual union all
    select 'BEAR', timestamp '2018-07-27 13:44:06', '7,3,9,3,3,6,11,39'    from dual union all
    select 'LION', timestamp '2018-07-27 16:03:09', '7,3,151,44,3,6,11,39' from dual union all
    select 'LION', timestamp '2018-07-27 16:03:49', '7,3,11,4,3,6,11,39'   from dual )
-- end of data */
select to_char(time_stamp, 'hh24:mi') ts, 
       sum(regexp_substr(counter_buff,'(.*?,){2}(.*?),', 1, 1,'', 2) + 
           regexp_substr(counter_buff,'(.*?,){5}(.*?),', 1, 1,'', 2)) sell, 
       sum(regexp_substr(counter_buff,'(.*?,){3}(.*?),', 1, 1,'', 2) + 
           regexp_substr(counter_buff,'(.*?,){6}(.*?),', 1, 1,'', 2)) retu
  from (select time_stamp, counter_buff, row_number() over (order by time_stamp desc) rn 
          from shops where toy_name = 'LION') t
  where rn <= 60
  group by to_char(time_stamp, 'hh24:mi')
```

In second I join two tables of predefined numbers with your data. These are the "user defined positions" used next as parameter for `regexp_substr`.

```
with 
  /* sample data
  shops(toy_name, time_stamp, counter_buff) as (
    select 'LION', timestamp '2018-07-27 13:15:27', '0,8,9,3,2,6,15,62'    from dual union all
    select 'BEAR', timestamp '2018-07-27 13:44:06', '7,3,9,3,3,6,11,39'    from dual union all
    select 'LION', timestamp '2018-07-27 16:03:09', '7,3,151,44,3,6,11,39' from dual union all
    select 'LION', timestamp '2018-07-27 16:03:49', '7,3,11,4,3,6,11,39'   from dual ),
  */ -- end of sample data
  sell as (select rownum rn, column_value cs from table(sys.odcinumberlist(2, 5)) ),
  retu as (select rownum rn, column_value cr from table(sys.odcinumberlist(3, 6)) )
select *
  from (
    select sum(regexp_substr(counter_buff,'(.*?,){'||cs||'}(.*?),', 1, 1,'', 2)) sell, 
           sum(regexp_substr(counter_buff,'(.*?,){'||cr||'}(.*?),', 1, 1,'', 2)) retu, ts
      from (select to_char(time_stamp, 'HH24:MI') ts, counter_buff 
              from (select * from shops where toy_name = 'LION' order by time_stamp desc) 
              where rownum <= 60)
      cross join sell join retu using (rn) group by ts)
  unpivot (val for status in (sell, retu))
```

In both queries I assumed that `sell` is in positions (2, 5), `returned` in positions (3, 6). Also try `row_number()` against `rownum` and check which is faster for you. In both cases data is hit only once, this should speed up calculations.